# Ajax call, where parameter is IRequest (Mediatr), has null in all properties

Tags: asp.net-core, mediatr

Here is my controller...

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    [Route("Account/json_account_log_in")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> json_account_log_in(ValidateUserQuery query)
    {
        ValidateUserDto response = await Mediator.Send(query);
        // Do stuf...
    }
}
```

And here is the query class..

```
public class ValidateUserQuery : IRequest<ValidateUserDto>
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }    
}
```

But in my controller, the query Username and Password are null.

If I remove the `IRequest<ValidateUserDto>` then Username and Password are correct - but then I can't use Mediatr.

Can't I use classes that inherits from IRequest in ajax calls queries?

Comment: If you can share a minimal reproducible sample, we would help troubleshoot the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

Solution ... I needed to add [FromBody]:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> json_account_log_in([FromBody] ValidateUserQuery query)
```

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved the issue. Besides, if you apply `[ApiController]` attribute to your AccountController class, it would also work well without specifying `[FromBody]`.